# R finding string patterns of a vector in elements of another (by pairs)

Tags: r, vector

I have a character vector

```
c1 <- c("BEL","BEL","BEL","BEL")
```

and another character vector of same length

```
c2 <- c(" BEL-65_DRe-I_1p:BEL;_LTR_Retrotransposon;_Transposable_Element;_Nonautonomous;_BEL-65_DRe-I", "L1-2_NN_3p:L1;_Non-LTR_Retrotransposon;_Transposable_Element;_L1-2_NN", "BEL-13_CQ-I_1p:BEL;_LTR_Retrotransposon;_Transposable_Element;_BEL-13_CQ_;_BEL-13_CQ-LTR;_BEL-13_CQ-I", "BEL-31_CQ-I_1p:BEL;_LTR_Retrotransposon;_Transposable_Element;_BEL-31_CQ_;_BEL-31_CQ-LTR;_BEL-31_CQ-I", "Gypsy-22_CQ-I_1p:Gypsy;_LTR_Retrotransposon;_Transposable_Element;_Gypsy-22_CQ_;_Gypsy-22_CQ-LTR;_Gypsy-22_CQ-I")
```

I want to know if each string in `c1` is found in `c2` at the same index (ignoring case), i.e. if `c1[1]` is found in`c2[1]`, `c1[2]` in `c2[2]`, and so on.
In practice, the vectors can have millions of elements.

My current solution is

```
test <- Map(function(x,y) grepl(x,y, ignore.case = T), c1, c2)
```

But it's not vectorised, hence relatively slow. 
Is there a better solution?

Comment: Have you tried `library(stringi);c1 <- stri_rand_strings(1e6, 2);c2 <- paste0(stri_rand_strings(1e6, 20), tolower(c1));system.time(res <- stri_detect(c2, fixed = c1, case_insensitive = TRUE))`?

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be a dedicated function. I even had stringi already installed, but there're so many functions in it it's hard to find the one you need. You can post this answer so I validate it.

Comment: Sure, just did so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This runs quite fast:

```
library(stringi)
c1 <- stri_rand_strings(1e6, 2)
c2 <- paste0(stri_rand_strings(1e6, 20), tolower(c1))
system.time(res <- stri_detect(c2, fixed = c1, case_insensitive = TRUE))
       # User      System verstrichen 
       # 0.73        0.00        0.75
```

Partly, because I did not check for a regular expression pattern but for a constant string (`fixed`), which you could also use in `grep*`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following using the stringr package:

```
require(stringr)
require(data.table)

data <- data.table(c1, c2)
data[, FOUND:= str_detect(toupper(c2), toupper(c1))]
```

Comment: Thanks, it should work just as well as the `stringi` solution.

Comment: Yes I think it's roughly the same.

Answer (score 1):

What would work as well, as your solutions is to use `apply`.
For this small example it works well, if it will be faster for bigger data, I do not know.

```
apply(rbind(c1,c2), 2, function(y){grepl(pattern = y[1],x=y[2], ignore.case = T)})
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Edited:
I had to add one more "BEL" to make it work, because your c1 consists of 4 elements and c2 of 5

Comment: thanks, I think it should work as well as `Map()` since they both rely on `for`loops internally.